# what does {% set order = 'pin desc, postDate desc' %} do?

Tags: order

I am new to using twig and I do not understand how this line of code works. If you could explain that would be wonderful! thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

Craft uses the the template engine [twig](https://twig.symfony.com) and there is a [set](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/set.html) tag that is the same as it's php equivalent for `$order = 'pin...'`

So you just set/declare a variable - in this case you set the string.